# Difference between nullptr, {} and nullopt

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, stdoptional

Why can't i use `nullptr` instead of `nullopt`? And why `{}` translates like `nullopt`?

Comment: You could have `std::optional<std::nullptr_t>` ;-)

Comment: An optional pointer that doesn't exist is different from a pointer that does exist and is `nullptr`. A default-initialised `optional` shouldn't have an object (and can't for non-default-constructible types). It seems obvious to me. Also, I wonder whether your questions could be answered by reading the papers that led to `std::optional` being accepted.

Comment: `nullptr` = "there is a pointer but it doesn't point to anything"; `nullopt`: "there is nothing".

Answer (score 11):

> Why can't i use `nullptr` instead of `nullopt`?

Because they're different things. They mean something different, and they're used for something different.

It's necessary to have a distinct `nullopt` value for use with `std::optional` because `nullptr` already does something:

```
std::optional<int*> o;
o = nullptr;
assert( o.has_value() );
o = std::nullopt;
assert( !o.has_value() );
```

> And why `{}` translates like `nullopt`?

(N.B. that is only true for `std:optional` not when using `{}` with other types.)

It does that because it's convenient to be able to say `o = {}` and have it Do The Right Thing™ and so the specification of `std::optional` is written to make it work.

Answer (score 9):

- `optional<T>` is not kind of pointer to `T`, it is a value that is
  either a `T` or is nothing. You cannot have a "dangling `optional`", or any other kind of "invalid" value, like you can with pointers and references.
- `nullptr` is an object that can be converted to a value of any pointer type.
- `nullopt` is an object that can be converted to a value of any `optional` type.
- `{}` is (in a context expecting a value) an expression that means "a
  default constructed object of type `T`", where `T` is some type inferred from the context. If `T` is a pointer type, it will compare equal to `nullptr`. If `T` is an `optional` type, it will compare equal to `nullopt`. If `T` is an arithmetic type, it will compare equal to `0`. If `T` is one of the standard container types, it will compare equal to other empty containers of that type.