# Why do we need std::nullopt

Tags: c++, c++17

When we can use uniform initialization to easily default construct a `std::optional<T>`?

```
std::optional<T> foo() {
   if (on_error)
      return {};

    // ...
}
```

Is there any drawback to the above which `std::nullopt` solves?

Comment: or [Difference between nullptr, {} and nullopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791737/difference-between-nullptr-and-nullopt/47794059#47794059

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No.**

This is a perfectly valid way to default-construct an `optional`.

Even for assignment, you can copy-assign a default-constructed `optional` with `= {}` instead of using `std::nullopt`:

cppreference actually [says as much](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t):

> The constraints on `nullopt_t`'s constructors exist to support both `op = {};` and `op = nullopt;` as the syntax for disengaging an optional object.

… as does the original [proposal for the feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#rationale.reset_syntax):

> Note that it is not the only way to disengage an optional object. You can also use:
>
> ```
> op = std::nullopt;
> ```

You might ask yourself why, then, `std::nullopt` exists at all. The proposal [addresses this, too](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#rationale.nullopt):

> it introduces redundancy into the interface
>
> *[similar example]*
>
> On the other hand, there are usages where the usage of nullopt cannot be replaced with any other convenient notation:
>
> ```
> void run(complex<double> v);
> void run(optional<string> v);
>
> run(nullopt);              // pick the second overload
> run({});                   // ambiguous
>
> if (opt1 == nullopt) ...   // fine
> if (opt2 == {}) ...        // illegal
>
> bool is_engaged( optional<int> o)
> {
>   return bool(o);          // ok, but unclear
>   return o != nullopt;     // familiar
> }
> ```
>
> While some situations would work with {} syntax, using nullopt makes the programmer's intention more clear. Compare these:
>
> ```
> optional<vector<int>> get1() {
>   return {};
> }
>
> optional<vector<int>> get2() {
>   return nullopt;
> }
>
> optional<vector<int>> get3() {
>   return optional<vector<int>>{};
> }
> ```

In short, `std::nullopt` can be useful, but in your case it simply comes down to style.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any drawback to the above which `std::nullopt` solves?

Yes.

In some contexts you may want to conditionally return a disengaged optional object (empty, if you’d like) and the `{}` initialization syntax cannot be non-ambiguously used to deduce the `std::nullopt_t` type. E.g., as is covered in [Return Optional value with ?: operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389872/return-optional-value-with-operator/45390238#45390238), when returning an empty or non-empty optional through a ternary operator expression:

> ```
> return it != map.end() ? std::make_optional(it->second) : std::nullopt;
> ```

Comment: am I correct that this only applies if the return type of the function is declared as `auto` ?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann No, you don't even need a function: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ICRS7wfj801CgGIf

Comment: The linked question is about a different case. Your `true` expression matches the return type. But, still, [`{}` isn't a valid expression there](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/222ee7027638ba2c).

Comment: This cleared things up, thank you